# Best way to atomically create files

Tags: php, filesystems, posix

The 'best practice' (as I see it) to atomically create a new file, is to open a temporary file (using [tmpfile()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)), and then moving the file to it's final location.

However, this won't work well if the temporary file is on a different mountpoint, as this will result in the file gradually building up and additionally result in unneeded IO overhead.

Another option is to create a temporary file in the same directory as the final destination, but this has the disadvantage of creating a unusual file for a user (Apps such as MS Word and ViM do this, but I also consider this bad behaviour).

Is there a similar method as tmpfile() that will allow me to specify the mountpoint? I realize this probably doesn't exist built-into PHP, so a Posix/C-function or shell-call is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maildir](http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html) protocol developed for `qmail` provides safe file creation for multiple writers to the same target directory, even across NFS.  In this scheme, the "tempfile" directory is guaranteed to be on the same filesystem as the target dir.

The algorithm is conveniently implemented in an efficient shell utility, [`safecat`](http://jeenyus.net/linux/software/safecat/safecat-man.html), whose manpage presents the algorithm as:

> safecat applies the maildir algorithm by writing data in six steps.
>   First, it stat()s the two directories tempdir and destdir, and exits
>   unless both directories exist and are writable. Second, it stat()s the
>   name tempdir/time.pid.host, where time is the number of seconds since
>   the beginning of 1970 GMT, pid is the program's process ID, and host is
>   the host name. Third, if stat() returned anything other than ENOENT,
>   the program sleeps for two seconds, updates time, and tries the stat()
>   again, a limited number of times. Fourth, the program creates
>   tempdir/time.pid.host. Fifth, the program NFS-writes the message to the
>   file. Sixth, the program link()s the file to destdir/time.pid.host. At
>   that instant the data has been successfully written.
>
> In addition, safecat starts a 24-hour timer before creat-ing
>   tempdir/time.pid.host, and aborts the write if the timer expires. Upon
>   error, timeout, or normal completion, safecat attempts to unlink()
>   tempdir/time.pid.host.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't such a method in the POSIX stack. tmpfile() and [tmpname()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tmpnam.html) use to normal temp dir. There is the [tempnam()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tempnam.html), where you can specific the target directory for the temp file. But is is basically a way to implement the second option you described.

Comment: I was curious if there was maybe some way to open an INode and only supply a filename down the road. I know it's possible to to open files, unlink the files, and then keep on writing.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but it would be nice to know exactly. If I remember, I will have a look at the VFS source code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about the "mountpoint" I'm assuming you are on a unix-like environment.

Maybe you can consider it a workaround or bad-behavior, but I think creating an hidden (.tmpfile) temp file on the same destination folder could be acceptable.

You can of course create a specific folder on the same mount point not accessible to the application suited for this task, simulating this way a tempfile() on the same mountpoint, if you don't want to see any spurious file in the destination dir.

Comment: This is actually exactly my second option, something I'd preferably like to avoid.

Comment: @Thorarin, can you gimme more info about this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had to do something like this and went with a MySQL DB. Just stored the info I needed in a table and when I was finished I just deleted the record. Just a thought :)

Comment: This might result in a similar amount of I/O overhead however. Often, the database isn't even on the same server.

Comment: Using MySQL is definitely worse